# css - overflow allow horizontal scroll

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I'm working on [this page](http://www4.wittenberg.edu/admission_dev/undergrad/) and I'm trying to get the overflow to allow for horizontal scrolls. I've tried setting the body to hidden and the class "real body" to auto. This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Could you please share your code? See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/4284627)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you need to wrap your long content div with a `position: relative; overflow: auto` div.

which i something like this:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30000px;
}
```

for a better example, please check http://jsfiddle.net/wXqPv/

Comment: Plus 1. The reason this works is because of the definite width.

Comment: so setting width to auto should work when the horizontal content is added?

Answer (score 1):

**The code below worked for me.**
Make sure to include it in the parent not the actual element itself.

```
.parent {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code with slide changes of above one:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    outline: 1px solid lime;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.longcontent {
   position: absolute;
   width: auto;
   height: 100%;
}
```