# [HTMl/CSS]List items goes below the navigation bar when scaling browser to small width

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make it stop going below the navigation bar when scaling the browser to a small width, here's what I mean(I can't post images because I don't have at least 10 rep)

But you can see for yourself here what I mean:

```
http://79.170.40.39/senixmenix.com/index.html
```

(Scale the width of the browser small, then you can see what I mean)

I'm still pretty new to Web Development, so there's still alot I don't understand,
hope you can help me :-)

Kind regards,
Jesper

Comment: Make what stop from going below the nav bar?

Comment: Oh, the list items(The navigation links, Home, News, etc. Sorry i mean the paragraph, i forgot i used paragraph instead

Comment: post code to you question, because url's can be invalid, and not every one want to connect to a ip (on work for example.)

Comment: It's an ip because i got free hosting, i bought a course for web development, and i haven't bought a domain, so they give a temporary domain. But of course i will post code next time, no problem :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the "SenixMenix" Logo is on the left, when the list items run out of room because the user is making the browser smaller they go below the "SenixMenix" logo because it is taking up to much space. What I would recomend doing is adding a media query at `637px`(That is when the list items hit the logo) to make a smaller logo appear.

```
.bigLogo{
    display: block;
}

.smallLogo{
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 637px){
    .bigLogo{
        display: none;
    }

    .smallLogo{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful to think about the behavior you want when the window is smaller. Do want it to just go off the screen instead of wrapping?

If so you can add a `min-width` to the header:

```
#header {
    min-width:700px;
}
```

This will fix it, but might not be ideal. A better idea is to read up on responsive design which will accommodate different sizes more gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

There is overflow due to the width of the items + logo vs. the small width of the screen. In order to display the information, it must go on the next line.

These two answers deal with horizontal scrolling + overflow

[Response 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178607/how-to-enable-horizontal-scroll-bar-for-html-ul-list)

[Response 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447782/css-overflow-allow-horizontal-scroll)

However, I would recommend looking into [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for styling. It has awesome stylesheets that will allow you to nit-pick through css less to get exactly what you're looking for. If bootstrap isn't your jazz, there a tons of other templates online!